# Passing Token to REST Api using Python

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

I know that there are a few question on SO that seem to answer this question but none of them get the job done for me.

So here is my code ...

```
import requests

bearer_token = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IlRFU1QifQ.eyJjbGllbnRpZCI6ImFhZDkyNjc5MmJiMjQ4YjRhZDcyYzk4ZDk0YTZhNTlhIiwidXNlcmlkIjoibmVpbC5oYXJsYW5kQG56cG9zdC5jby5ueiIsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoibmVpbC5oYXJsYW5kQG56cG9zdC5jby5ueiIsImV4cCI6MTQ4MTA2ODM0MSwic2NvcGUiOltdLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJhYWQ5MjY3OTJiYjI0OGI0YWQ3MmM5OGQ5NGE2YTU5YSJ9.BaQk5kCmIWSd2PB2QtT0nbyG5a8FWxSudcbTsS4RvLA'
url = 'https://myapi/apiname/apiversion/endpoint/flow?param1=253&param2=20'

def callMyApi():
  print ("Calling API ...")
  response = requests.get(url,headers={'Authorization': bearer_token})
  print (response.text)

callMyApi()
```

Here is the respobse I get ...

```
Calling API ...
{ "error": "missing_access_token", "description": "The access token is missing." }
```

Now I have tried many varieties such as ...

```
response = requests.get(url,headers={'Authorization': 'token' +  bearer_token})

response = requests.get(url,headers={'Authorization': 'Basic' +  bearer_token})
```

I have even tried base64 encoding just in case there was something interesting happening with that complex bearer_token - even though it is just a string

And nothing works.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Maybe token must be passed inside get request as parameter?
I.e. api.service?token={{token}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys - turns out that the problem lay between the keyboard and the chair :-)

The code I posted works fine - the actual bearer_token requires the word 'Bearer' in front. Once I added this it worked

Answer (score 0):

In Django `TokenAuthentication` REST API, `headers` should be as below:

```
headers = {'Authorization': 'Token ' +  bearer_token} 
                             ^^^^^^
                               ⎿________________________ # Note  

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```